# T-SQL Reset Row number when field changes, including repeated instances

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to find a way to show how many consecutive times an event types happens before a second event type happens.  When I have that I need to show when an event type happens 6 times in a row

To simplify I have a 'Calls' table containing

```
CallID
UserID
Outcome
DateOfCall
```

From there I have numerous `UserID`s with outcome as `Yes` or `No` at various times

I need to find when No happens 6 times in a row

I'm currently using Partition and have got it to count the number of `Outcome`s per `UserID`, but i am struggling to reset the Row Number when the `Outcome` changes for a 2nd time per `UserID`

```
 select  CallID,
        UserID,
        Outcome,
        DateOfCall
        rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID , outcome ORDER BY DateOfCall ASC)
        from    Calls
        order by UserID, DateOfCall
```

Gives me the following for a UserID

```
- 19/01/2017 12:00 - Yes - 1 
- 19/01/2017 12:01 - Yes - 2
- 19/01/2017 12:02 - Yes - 3
- 19/01/2017 12:03 - No  - 1
- 19/01/2017 12:04 - No  - 2
- 19/01/2017 12:05 - No  - 3
- 19/01/2017 12:06 - Yes - 4
- 19/01/2017 12:07 - Yes - 5
- 19/01/2017 12:08 - No  - 4
- 19/01/2017 12:09 - No  - 5
- 19/01/2017 12:10 - No  - 6
```

As you can see the call at `12:10` will trigger as it is the 6th 'No' event, however only 3 happened in a row on both occasions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do what you want using the "difference of row numbers" approach:

```
select c.*,
       row_number() over (partition by userid, outcome, seqnum_u - seqnum_uo
                          order by dateofcall
                         ) as rnk
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by userid order by dateofcall) as seqnum_u,
             row_number() over (partition by userid, outcome order by dateofcall) as seqnum_uo
      from Calls c
     ) c
order by UserID, DateOfCall;
```

This logic is tricky the first time you see it (hey, maybe even the third or fifth time too).  I advise you to run the inner query so you can see why the difference identifies groups of adjacent status values.  Then the `row_number()` in the outer query make more sense.

Comment: Wow, thankyou for the quick response. That seems to do the trick perfectly

Comment: Sorry, now when i try to add a 'Where rnk >= 6' i get a syntax error for invalid column name. How would i go about using this rnk column to get the lines required?

Comment: @Glyn . . . You need another level of subquery to use `rnk` in a `where` clause.

Comment: apologies, thought i had responded here. Got sorted there, worked a charm. Thanks

Comment: That was awesome. Thanks so much.