# SQL rownumber until column value changes back

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, row-number

I am trying to create a column that represents how many days ago the most recent promotion started for each product. It should continue counting on when the promotion ended, until the next promotion starts.

For example, I want the following:

| product | date | in_promo | days_since_last_promo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-01 | false | null |
| 1 | 2023-10-02 | false | null |
| 1 | 2023-10-03 | true | 0 |
| 1 | 2023-10-04 | true | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-10-05 | true | 2 |
| 1 | 2023-10-06 | false | 3 |
| 1 | 2023-10-07 | false | 4 |
| 1 | 2023-10-08 | true | 0 |
| 1 | 2023-10-09 | true | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-10-10 | false | 2 |

Particularly, I'm having trouble getting the right `days_since_last_promo` for these lines:

| product | date | in_promo | days_since_last_promo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-06 | false | 3 |
| 1 | 2023-10-07 | false | 4 |

I've been puzzling with lags, row_number() and partition by's but I can't figure it out. Is this even possible in SQL?

I would say it's related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41745368/t-sql-reset-row-number-when-field-changes-including-repeated-instances), but we're trying to achieve something slightly different.

I tried for example

```
select 
  product
  , date
  , in_promo
  , row_number() over (partition by recipe_id, in_promo, seqnum_u - seqnum_uo
                      order by date_cet
    ) as days_since_last_promo
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by product order by date) as seqnum_u,
             row_number() over (partition by product, in_promo order by date) as seqnum_uo
      from product_sales_data as p
      )
```

But that will give me

| product | date | in_promo | days_since_last_promo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-01 | false | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-10-02 | false | 2 |
| 1 | 2023-10-03 | true | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-10-04 | true | 2 |
| 1 | 2023-10-05 | true | 3 |
| 1 | 2023-10-06 | false | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-10-07 | false | 2 |
| 1 | 2023-10-08 | true | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-10-09 | true | 2 |
| 1 | 2023-10-10 | false | 1 |

i.e. restarting the row_number when `in_promo=false`.

Comment: The real unknown here is the promotion start dates.  Can they be inferred from the data? If so, then it's simple datediff arithmetic.  I think you are assuming that there will be at least one table record for each date, because if your table was missing the third record (for example) you could not tell if that promotion began on 10/3 or 10/4.  So if that is so, then first in an inner SQL identify the dates when in_promo changed from FALSE to TRUE (`Case When Not lag(in_promo)... and in_promo Then date End`) then in an outer SQL propagate that date to the other records and do the datediff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a solution using ORACLE syntax but with standard analytic functions, assuming the start of the promotion is the first date in_promo for a sequence of rows ( in_promo* !in_promo+ ) (should be easier with MATCH_RECOGNIZE but would be ORACLE-only):

```
with data(product, dat, in_promo) as (
    select 1, date '2023-10-01', 'false' from dual union all
    select 1, date '2023-10-02', 'false' from dual union all
    select 1, date '2023-10-03', 'true' from dual union all
    select 1, date '2023-10-04', 'true' from dual union all
    select 1, date '2023-10-05', 'true' from dual union all
    select 1, date '2023-10-06', 'false' from dual union all
    select 1, date '2023-10-07', 'false' from dual union all
    select 1, date '2023-10-08', 'true' from dual union all
    select 1, date '2023-10-09', 'true' from dual union all
    select 1, date '2023-10-10', 'false' from dual
)
select d.product, d.dat, 
    sum(ndays) over(partition by product, grp order by dat) as days_since_last_promo
from (
    select d.*,
        case when in_promo = 0 and grp = 0 then null
        else
            nvl(
                dat - last_value(dat) over(partition by product, grp order by dat 
                    rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding),
                0
            )
        end
        as ndays
    from (
        select d.*, 
            sum(change) over(partition by product order by dat) as grp
        from (
            select d.*, 
                decode(in_promo,1,
                    decode(1,lag(in_promo) over(partition by product order by dat),0,1),
                    0
                ) as change
            from (select product, dat, decode(in_promo,'true',1,0) as in_promo from data) d
        ) d
    ) d
) d
order by dat
;


1   01/10/2023 00:00:00 
1   02/10/2023 00:00:00 
1   03/10/2023 00:00:00 0
1   04/10/2023 00:00:00 1
1   05/10/2023 00:00:00 2
1   06/10/2023 00:00:00 3
1   07/10/2023 00:00:00 4
1   08/10/2023 00:00:00 0
1   09/10/2023 00:00:00 1
1   10/10/2023 00:00:00 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is that you tag each record that either originates as true (in promotion) or switches from false to true, first new occurrence of a promotion.

Then a self join to get the last date of an earlier change and take the difference. There is cleaner syntax with inline correlated subqueries that most dbms's support to avoid the self join, but I wasn't sure about bigquery.

Then adjust by 1.

This is in postgres, but I think bigquery supports all the syntax.

https://dbfiddle.uk/dYbyXMGP

```
create table some_sample_data 
  ( product integer,
    _date date,
    in_promo varchar(100)
  )

insert into some_sample_data values (1, '2023-10-01', 'false');
insert into some_sample_data values (1, '2023-10-02', 'false');
insert into some_sample_data values (1, '2023-10-03', 'true');
insert into some_sample_data values (1, '2023-10-04', 'true');
insert into some_sample_data values (1, '2023-10-05', 'true');
insert into some_sample_data values (1, '2023-10-06', 'false');
insert into some_sample_data values (1, '2023-10-07', 'false');
insert into some_sample_data values (1, '2023-10-08', 'true');
insert into some_sample_data values (1, '2023-10-09', 'true');
insert into some_sample_data values (1, '2023-10-10', 'false');
insert into some_sample_data values (2, '2023-10-01', 'true');
insert into some_sample_data values (2, '2023-10-03', 'false');
insert into some_sample_data values (2, '2023-10-04', 'false');
insert into some_sample_data values (2, '2023-10-05', 'true');

with sequenced_result as (
      SELECT 
        *,
        case when in_promo = 'true'
              and coalesce(lag(in_promo) OVER(PARTITION BY product ORDER BY cast(_date as date) asc),'false') = 'false'
             then 1
             else 0
          end originated_as_or_change_to_true
    FROM some_sample_data
  ),
  earlier_snapshots as (
  select t1.*,
         max(t2._date) as date_of_last_change
    from sequenced_result t1
    left
    join sequenced_result t2
      on t1.product = t2.product
     and t1._date >= t2._date
     and t2.originated_as_or_change_to_true = 1
   group
      by t1.product,
         t1._date,
         t1.in_promo,
         t1.originated_as_or_change_to_true
  )
  select product,
         _date,
         in_promo,
         _date - date_of_last_change + 1 as days_since_last_promo
    from earlier_snapshots
   order 
      by product, 
         _date
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [@p3consulting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77566752/23001829)! I parsed your code into SQL server again, in case anyone else needs it:

```
select d.product, d.date, in_promo,
  sum(ndays) over(partition by product, grp order by date) as days_since_last_promo
from (
  select d.*,
    case 
      when not in_promo and grp = 0 then null
      else
        coalesce(
          date_diff(date, 
                    last_value(date) over(partition by product, grp order by date
                      rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
                    , day
          ),
          0
        )
      end as ndays
  from (
    select d.*, 
      sum(change) over(partition by product order by date) as grp
    from (
      select *, 
        case 
          when in_promo then (case 
              when lag(in_promo) over(partition by product order by date) then 0 
              else 1 
              end)
          else 0
          end as change
      from data
    ) d
  ) d
) d
order by product, date
```